# What to do when a link refers to a non-English site?

Tags: discussion, answers, languages

Consider [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/511144/how-to-instruct-web-browsers-not-to-cache-pages/517507#517507) answer. [This](http://www.httpviewer.net/) is the link which is mentioned in the answer which is a site fully written other than English.

What to do in this case?

Comment: I would comment on that post(Please write your answer in English.Stack Overflow is an English-only site, and all the questions and answers must be in English) .After few days(if I come back) I would flag it as VLQ.

Comment: In the specific case of [that answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/511144/how-to-instruct-web-browsers-not-to-cache-pages/517507#517507), it should be deleted as an **expired link**.  The domain was obviously repurposed

Comment: @DrewDormann do you realize that your edit was probably harmful.  If there were any active flags on the post, you invalidated them with your stupid edit (although I realize the chances were low on a 5 year old post , but you never know).  Never edit crap.  Downvote and flag.

Comment: @DrewDormann edits automatically dismiss Low Quality flags and remove such posts from the review queue.  So don't edit Low Quality stuff unless it is really harmful to the site,

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As [@Drew Dormann](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299656/what-to-do-when-a-link-refers-to-local-language-site#comment222518_299656) mentions, it was probably a link that died a long time ago and was repurposed for another reason.

However, Drew's solution to the problem was wrong.  Never edit a bad Answer, even if it is to remove a dead link.

If the link in a low quality answer is not actively **harmful** (i.e. not linking to something that is NSFW), then you should never remove the link (or edit the post at all).  Just downvote and flag.  The reason is that edits to answers can actually automatically kick posts out of some of the review queues and cancel flags.  So the mere act of editing out the link can keep the answer around longer.  Exceptions should be made for good answers with bad links - but that is a separate issue.

If the link is "Not Suitable For Work", then editing may be appropriate, but be sure to downvote and flag it **after** you edit just in case you automatically dismissed any flags because of your edit.  But if the link is just bad but does not contain any NSFW material, you should refrain from editing, and just downvote and flag again.

When the answer is bad, the goal is to get the post deleted as quickly as possible, so edits to the post potentially impede that goal because the edits can potentially remove the post from the Low Quality Review Queue.

Comment: Note that a bad answer is not the same as a bad post. I think that `Never edit a bad post` should be rephrased as this implies that you reviewed the post and found it unsalvageable. Editing to improve [is encouraged](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit), including "to correct minor mistakes or add addendums / updates as the post ages".

Comment: @BlasSoriano good point.  I havr clarified that

Comment: related feature request at MSE: [Edits shouldn't dismiss “not an answer” flags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/252854/165773)

Answer (score 1):

psubsee2003's answer address only that specific answer and link, however he doesn't address the actual question in the title. So:

Answers should be valid and complete **without** links. An answer that results incomplete if the links become broken is a bad answer and should either be deleted as link-only, or flagged as low quality and downvoted.
However adding some links to expand on certain points, clarify some steps or provide further information is welcome.

If an answer is valid and complete without having to read the material linked, it doesn't really matter whether the links are to non-English sites.

You should change those links only when:

1. You are in this situation (i.e. the answer is already valid and complete. If not handle as psubsee2003 said)
2. The website linked *does* have an English-version page
3. The English-version page contains the same relevant information

For example: you may change the link from a wikipedia page on subject X to the page on subject X in English, *when the English page contains the same relevant information* (this is *usually* the case, but there may be exceptions where the English page is **not** suitable).

I would **not** replace a link with a different English site although containing almost the same information without letting the answerer know.

For example changing a link from site X to site Z, which is completely unrelated to X except that it contains a page with the same information but in English, doesn't sound appropriate. In this case it's better to just comment the question providing the link and asking the answerer to include it in the answer (or edit the answer to **add** that link, without removing the original).

Moreover, be very careful when you aren't an expert on the subject and you haven't thoroughly read *both* articles since you may miss some important information contained in the original link.

Comment: I think it's also always a good idea to comment and let the poster know that SO is English only, even if you're telling them that the answer was good.

Comment: If the link points to non-english content, there should be a marker `(elbonian)` or the like.